# Default attributes from custom field type does not show up in HTML

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I'm trying to implement an Facebook style autocomplete field using a custom form type. The JavaScript widget depends on a class name so I added it to the attr key in the custom form type class as I have done at other places, but for some reason it never gets displayed in the output HTML :-(

The relevant code:

```
class AutocompleteType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'autocomplete',
                'data-autocomplete' => '{"url":"'.$options['url'].'"}'
            )

        );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'url' => false,
            'object' => false,
            'repository' => false,
            'field' => false
        ));

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new AutocompleteTransformer($this->em, $options['object'], $options['repository'], $options['field']);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
            'url' => $options['url'],
            'object' => $options['object'],
            'repository' => $options['repository'],
            'field' => $options['field']
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'autocompleter';
    }
}
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="post[Tags]" id="post_Tags">
```

Expected HTML

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" data-autocomplete="url/passed/from/builder" required="required" name="post[Tags]" id="post_Tags">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three ways, I don't know what is better

1) under buildForm() method you can get and set attribute 'attr':

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $attrs = $builder->getAttribute('attr');
    ...
    $builder->setAttribute('attr', $attrs);
}
```

2) another way is to set attributes under build view, I think it's a bit more logic

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge(array(
        ....
    ), $view->vars['attr']);
}
```

3) latest way is to pass them directly as variables in the view and not in the 'attr', then display them in the appropriate twig block.

I think the third one is the best way but i'm not sure.